# Python Pandas: reusing row value to another row - lookup across row

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup, lookup

I have the following data frame

```
df1 =  DataFrame([['OBJ1', 10, 'BX', 'pool1', 'OBJ2'],['OBJ2', 0, '', '', 'OBJ1'],['OBJ3', 10, 'BY', 'pool2', 'OBJ4'],['OBJ4', 0, '', '', 'OBJ3'],['OBJ5', 10, 'BZ', 'pool3', '']], columns=['OBJ', 'value', 'conf', 'Res', 'Key'])
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is to:

- check when value is 0
- Conf and Res takes the value of the row with the key matching the OBJ
- for example, OBJ2 value is 0 and it is key is OBJ 2, then it's conf should become BX and Res becomes pool1

I tried multiple solutions using either lookup or some other posts but nothing seems to work.

```
df1.loc[df1['value']==0, 'conf'] = df1.loc[df1['OBJ']==df1['Key']]['conf']
```

failed as I realized this is looking for rows with OBJ = Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left_on` and `right_on` parameters and `index` column created by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for new `DataFrame`, then convert `index` column to `index` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last set new volumns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df1['value'].eq(0)
cols = ['conf','Res']
df = (df1.reset_index().loc[m, ['index','OBJ']]
          .merge(df1, left_on='OBJ', right_on='Key')
          .set_index('index')[cols])
print (df)
      conf    Res
index            
1       BX  pool1
3       BY  pool2

df1.loc[m, cols] = df
print (df1)
    OBJ  value conf    Res   Key
0  OBJ1     10   BX  pool1  OBJ2
1  OBJ2      0   BX  pool1  OBJ1
2  OBJ3     10   BY  pool2  OBJ4
3  OBJ4      0   BY  pool2  OBJ3
4  OBJ5     10   BZ  pool3
```